# How do I change the color scheme for .txt files to always be the default scheme in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I like to change around my default color scheme in my text editors. I love Sublime and use it for a lot of .txt documents. I don't like the default white-on-gray scheme that is uses though.

I saw other answers about how to change a specific background color based on the file type, but I haven't come across anything about making a specific file type use the default setting.

I would like any text file I open/create in sublime to use the same color scheme as what I currently have selected from the preferences menu.

Comment: It will. Once you put `"color_scheme": "Packages/MyScheme/MyScheme.tmTheme"` in your user preferences, all newly-opened files should have the new scheme.

Comment: @MattDMo I have the following in my preferences: `{
 "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Cobalt.tmTheme",
 "font_size": 10,
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ]
}
` When I create a new file I get the desired scheme, but when I save the file as .txt (or open a .txt file) I get a different color scheme that I don't want to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a `.txt` file in Sublime, then select **`Preferences -> Settings-More -> Syntax Specific-User`** to open `Packages/User/Plain text.sublime-settings`. More than likely there is a line in there setting the color scheme to Monokai, which is Sublime's default. Just delete that line, save the file, and you should be all set.

Comment: Turned out that the Markdown package was overriting the color scheme for txt files. Your solution helped me find that since when I opend the file you described, it instead opened Markdown.sublime-settings. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I too had issues with my text file color scheme in Sublime text. The scheme was centered dark-gray text on a light-gray background, very hard to read.

### Look in the settings for any Markdown packages you have installed

Based on @BrianHVB's comment in the accepted answer about the Markdown package, I looked up the settings for the MD package I was using.

In my case, the settings had a list of file extensions for which the package would activate. The list included `txt` files. I opened the User settings file for the MD package, and overwrote the `extensions` setting. Once I reopened my `txt` the color scheme was back to normal.

I don't know why `txt` files had a gray background, while `md` files were fine. Perhaps that answer is elsewhere in the package settings, but I lost interest after I fixed my problem.

**Markdown.sublime-settings - User**

```
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "md",
        "mdown"
    ]
}
```

#### This is how I got to the User settings file for the package

[image]

Comment: My .txt files have always been with a bright background. Didn't know why. You saved my eyes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Changed manually. Go to C: \ Program Files \ Sublime Text 3 \ Packages \ Color Scheme - Legacy.Sublime-Package. Opens the archiver. Get the topic file that the monokai bright.tmtheme is editing. We open a variable color in the editor and looking for. I blinded my eyes brightly red. Changed it on # 769AF5.

[search colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0wfu.png)
Result.
[the end result is visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrNN2.png)

P.S. I apologize for not a poetic syllable, because English is not native to me :))